# Displaying detailed data from multiple Django models in html

Tags: python, django

I have the below Django model. As you can see, the directory of each strain is dynamic, and the Photos_save model is inline to the strain model (it lets me save multiple photos for each strain). I would like to have a detailed view of each strain and the pictures associated with it. Could any of you help me with the views.py and HTML code required to accomplish this? I'm quite new to Django, and so far I have managed to display all of the information of the strain, including the photos, on the index page (but I want the users to be able to click on the name of each strain and see a detailed view).

```
class Strain(models.Model):
    """;
    Model representing strains.
    """
    type_strain = (
        ('W', 'Wild Type'),
        ('G', 'GMO'),
        ('P', 'Prospected'),
    )

    def strain_directory_path(instance, filename):
        return 'strain_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.strain_name, filename)

    strain_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=True, default=None)
    strain_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    data_of_generation = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default= None)
    strain_source = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    strain_parent = models.ForeignKey('Strain', null=True, blank = True, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default= None)
    strain_type = models.CharField(max_length=1 , blank=True, null=True, default=None, choices= type_strain)

class Photos_save(models.Model):
    import datetime
    def strain_directory_path(instance, filename):
        return 'strain_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.strain_name, filename)



    strain_name = models.ForeignKey(Strain, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default= None)
    upload_photo = models.FileField(upload_to= strain_directory_path, default= None)
    photo_description = models.CharField(max_length= 200, default= None, blank= True)
    photo_upload_date = models.DateField(blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)


    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object.
        """
        return '{0}'.format(self.strain_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a particular photo instance.
        """
        return reverse('photo-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: You can iterate over `strain.photos_save_set.all` in the detail template.

Comment: This is my html code for the page and nothing is showing up.{% for strain in strain.photos_save_set.all %}

<h1>Strain Name: {{ strain.strain_name }}</h1>
<p><strong>Strain Description:</strong> {{ strain.strain_description }}</p>

<a><img src="{{ strain.upload_photo.url }}" width="500px"/></a>

{% endfor %}

Comment: it actually works now, thanks!